# android: remote service vs sharedUserId?

Tags: android

What is different in these two approaches : remote service (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) vs sharedUserId (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html)? 
What is adv/Disadv each of them?

Comment: What is your specific question?

Comment: Which of these two approaches is better to use for sharing data between, for example, 3 applications, where one of them contains shared resources?